# What are these letters at the end of closing credits?

Tags: credits, 20th-century-women

In *[20th Century Women](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4385888/)*, I find some letters at the end of the closing credits.

[image: Screenshot stating JM KM MA MJ + HM]

What are these?

Comment: Dedications to the real persons behind the characters in this semi-autobiographical movie. But I don't know them; I guess JM is Janet Mills.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> JM = Janet Meyer/Jan Mills, his mom
>       KM = Most likely his oldest sister, but I can't find confirmation on her first name
>       MA = Megan Ace, his older sister
>       MJ = Miranda July, his wife
>       HM = Hopper Mills, his son

- Source for names: http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2017/01/09/mike-mills-anti-hollywood-family-films